# Laravel Validator return keys, not errors

Tags: laravel

[$errors->all()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEjgc.png)

i use default validation, like:

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'name' => 'required|max:255' // etc..
])
enter code here
```

How i can fix that? I didn`t touch any core files, only install some libraries

In view i get them like this:

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)

 {{ $error }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: have u tried $error->name??

Comment: @Jigs1212, its not a object.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In fact, it was easier, I just didn't have a translation for mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can print your errors with these ways in blade template:-

First one:-

```
@if ($errors->has('field_name'))
{{ $errors->first('field_name') }}
@endif
```

Second one:-

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Oh,
you are using validator,
Okay

Comment: if ($validation->passes()) {
// Do something here
} else {
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
}

Comment: Try this, It'll helpful for you

Comment: and what to do - if I use the built-in auth? (make:auth)

Comment: Can you please show me, how did you validate your input?

Comment: Why you're creating validator function, You can do it like this:-
If you want to write code directly in controller:- do this thing

$validation = Validator::make($data, ['field_name' => 'required']);
if ($validation->passes()) {
// Do Something
}else{
 
 return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
}

Comment: otherwise i'll advise you create a request file and write your validation rule and validation message there. That will be perfect.

Comment: Okay, it was easier. For some reason I had another language, and there were no files with translations for it